# Is it possible to connect MySQL to Scavis/DataMelt directly without use of Java

Tags: mysql

I would like to connect a MySQL Database directly to DataMelt (formerly called SCaViS) (without the use of java) in order to represent data in diagrams directly from the database. Is this it possible to do so?  Are there any limitations or challenges if I would do?